# Perform "get" on all HashMap elements of a LazySeq

Tags: clojure, hashmap, lazy-sequences

I'm parsing some XML data from Stack Exchange using `clojure.data.xml`, for example if I parse Votes data it returns a LazySeq containing a HashMap for each row of data.

What I am trying to do is to get the values associated with only certain keys, for each row,e.g., `(get votes [:Id :CreationDate])`. I've tried numerous things, most of them leading to casting errors.

The closest I could get to what I need is using `(doall (map get votes [:Id :CreationDate]))`. However, the problem I am experiencing now is that I cannot seem to return more than just the first row (i.e. `(1 2011-01-19T00:00:00.000)`)

Here is a MCVE that can be run on any Clojure REPL, or [on Codepad online IDE](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/ChilledNebulousValueBaggage).

Ideally I would like to return some kind of collection or map which contains the values I need for each row, the end goal is to write to something like a CSV file or such. For example a map like

> ```
> (1 2011-01-19T00:00:00.000
>  2 2011-01-19T00:00:00.000
>  3 2011-01-19T00:00:00.000
>  4 2011-01-19T00:00:00.000)
> ```

```
(def votes '({:Id "1",
              :PostId "2",
              :VoteTypeId "2",
              :CreationDate "2011-01-19T00:00:00.000"}
             {:Id "2",
              :PostId "3",
              :VoteTypeId "2",
              :CreationDate "2011-01-19T00:00:00.000"}
             {:Id "3",
              :PostId "1",
              :VoteTypeId "2",
              :CreationDate "2011-01-19T00:00:00.000"}
             {:Id "4",
              :PostId "1",
              :VoteTypeId "2",
              :CreationDate "2011-01-19T00:00:00.000"}))

  (println (doall (map get votes [:Id :CreationDate])))
```

---

Additional detail: If this is of any help/interest, the code I am using to get the above lazy seq is as follows:

```
(ns se-datadump.read-xml
  (require
    [clojure.data.xml :as xml])

(def xml-votes
  "<votes><row Id=\"1\" PostId=\"2\" VoteTypeId=\"2\" CreationDate=\"2011-01-19T00:00:00.000\" />  <row Id=\"2\" PostId=\"3\" VoteTypeId=\"2\" CreationDate=\"2011-01-19T00:00:00.000\" />  <row Id=\"3\" PostId=\"1\" VoteTypeId=\"2\" CreationDate=\"2011-01-19T00:00:00.000\" />  <row Id=\"4\" PostId=\"1\" VoteTypeId=\"2\" CreationDate=\"2011-01-19T00:00:00.000\" /></votes>")

(defn se-xml->rows-seq
  "Returns LazySequence from a properly formatted XML string,
  which contains a HashMap for every <row> element with each of its attributes.
  This assumes the standard Stack Exchange XML format, where a parent element contains
  only a series of <row> child elements with no further hierarchy."
  [xml-str]
  (let [xml-records (xml/parse-str xml-str)]
        (map :attrs (-> xml-records :content))))

; this returns a map identical as in the MCVE:
(def votes (se-xml->rows-seq xml-votes)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your intention completely. Could you maybe provide a manually created sample result? than it's easier to tell.

Comment: @AntonHarald I added an example desired result, hope this helps make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You apparently need `juxt`:

```
(map (juxt :Id :CreationDate) votes)
;; => (["1" "2011-01-19T00:00:00.000"] ["2" "2011-01-19T00:00:00.000"] ["3" "2011-01-19T00:00:00.000"] ["4" "2011-01-19T00:00:00.000"])
```

If you need a map out of it:

```
(into {} (map (juxt :Id :CreationDate) votes))
;; => {"1" "2011-01-19T00:00:00.000", "2" "2011-01-19T00:00:00.000", "3" "2011-01-19T00:00:00.000", "4" "2011-01-19T00:00:00.000"}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let me explain, what the piece of code you suggest in the CodePad is actually doing. I doubt that it's the thing you are intending to do:

```
(println (doall (map get votes [:Id :CreationDate])))
```

The crucial part is: `(map get votes [:Id :CreationDate])`
This maps over two collections: the lazy sequence 'votes' and a vector. Whenever mapping over more than one collection, the returned lazy sequence will be as long as the shortest collection provided.
For instance one can map over a finite collection and an infinite sequence:

```
(map + (range) [1 2 3])
;; (0 3 5)
```

This explains why yours result is only two items long:

```
(map get votes [:Id :CreationDate])
```

reduces to:

```
((get (votes 0) ([:Id :CreationDate] 0)
 (get (votes 1) ([:Id :CreationDate] 1))
```

reduces to:

```
((get {:Id "1",
       :PostId "2",
       :VoteTypeId "2",
       :CreationDate "2011-01-19T00:00:00.000"} :Id)
 (get {:Id "2",
       :PostId "3",
       :VoteTypeId "2",
       :CreationDate "2011-01-19T00:00:00.000"} :CreationDate))
```

reduces finally to:

```
(1 2011-01-19T00:00:00.000)
```

This is just for understanding purpose. If the compiler does exactly these steps, is another question.

`doall` is not necessary here, since `println` already does this implicitly.

---

As already noted. In your case you'd better use `juxt` and only map over votes. If you really want to have the sample output you additionally need to flatten the output:

```
(flatten (map (juxt :Id :CreationDate) votes))
```

Comment: That makes sense, didn't think of it that way. Thanks for the explanation!